# Is there a way to return the manager of a user from an LDAP query?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

A co-worker has tasked me with creating an LDAP query for a new application he's setting up, PowerBroker. The goal is to pull the list of managers for all of the users in an OU if they have a particular AD attribute, let's call it "SecurityLevel". The OU has the current administrative accounts and the "managers" are the standard accounts of the users they belong to.

This is pretty easy to do in Powershell, but we'd like the tool to automatically update as we create new admin accounts and the tool has a field to use an LDAP query. I'm new to LDAP queries, but thought it would be simple. Unfortunately, it's proving more difficult than I anticipated.

I was thinking it would look something along the lines of *(manager)(SecurityLevel=1)*.

The powershell for it looks something like this:

```
$SecondaryAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SecondaryAccounts,OU=USERS,DC=example,DC=com" -Properties Name, manager, SecurityLevel
foreach ($account in $SecondaryAccounts)
{
    if ($account.SecurityLevel -eq 1)
    {
        $PrimaryAccount = $account.Manager
        Write-Host "Type 1 account: $PrimaryAccount"
    }
}
```

Any recommendations on how to get the manager information?

Comment: In what language and using what LDAP API?

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking it would look something along the lines of (manager)(SecurityLevel=1).

Close. As an LDAP query, it should be this:

```
(&(manager=*)(SecurityLevel=1))
```

That means: If the `manager` attribute has a value and the `SecurityLevel` attribute is equal to `1`.

To use an LDAP query with `Get-ADUser`, you need to use the `-LDAPFilter` parameter:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(manager=*)(SecurityLevel=1))" -SearchBase "OU=SecondaryAccounts,OU=USERS,DC=example,DC=com" -Properties Name, manager, SecurityLevel
```

The `-Filter` parameter uses PowerShell style conditions, and allows you to use the property names that `Get-ADUser` exposes rather than the raw AD attribute names (e.g. "Surname" instead of "sn"). In that format, the same conditions would look like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "manager -like '*' -and SecurityLevel -eq 1" -SearchBase "OU=SecondaryAccounts,OU=USERS,DC=example,DC=com" -Properties Name, manager, SecurityLevel
```

The manager attribute contains the `distinguishedName` of the manager's account. So you can pass that into `Get-ADUser` to read the manager's account. All of that together will look something like this:

```
$SecondaryAccounts = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(manager=*)(SecurityLevel=1))" -SearchBase "OU=SecondaryAccounts,OU=USERS,DC=example,DC=com" -Properties Name, manager, SecurityLevel
foreach ($account in $SecondaryAccounts)
{
    $PrimaryAccount = Get-ADUser $account.Manager
    Write-Host "Type 1 account: $($PrimaryAccount.Name)"
}
```